# Can't connect from Vue to .NET Core API on Docker

Tags: .net, docker, api, vue.js

I have to make a request from a Vue frontend solution to a .NET Core (3.1) backend API. Running it normally (without Docker), works without any problem, but I have to dockerize them (separately) and make them work, which I'm not able to do.

Vue Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install

# start app
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Vue Docker Run command:

> docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 8081:8080 --rm dockerized-vue:front

.NET Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy rest of the files
COPY . .

# Build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

.NET Docker Run command:

> docker run -p 8082:8080 --rm dockerized-netcore:back

.NET Core launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:58726",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "myapp",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "myapp",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8082",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sending the request from Vue to

> http://localhost:8082/api/MyEndpoint

Also have to add that I initially used port 5000 for local test (without docker) but I decided to change to port 8082 since Docker tells me that port 5000 is already in use (don't know why...)

Thanks.

Comment: are you sending the specified request from the vue app's container, or from the browser, through the vue app?

Comment: also, why are you forwarding to 8080 instead of port 80 in your web api?

Comment: @4ng3L you're probably referencing the container's `localhost` instead of the host machine `localhost`, please try connecting from the Vue app using the host machine IP address and port 8082 as you specified for the .NET backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the aspnet image you use as a base for your image, Microsoft set the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable to `http://+:80` which overrides your launchsettings file.

That means that you should map the port on your host to port 80 in the image like this

```
docker run -p 8082:80 --rm dockerized-netcore:back
```

A good way to be certain about which port the app is listening on (because there are a lot of ways to set it, so it can be hard to be sure which setting wins) is to run the command `docker logs <container name>`. Then you'll see something like this

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

Here you can see which port it's listening on.

Comment: That's it! thank you (again :D) @HansKilian first time using Docker, this info helps me a lot to understand it better not just for making it work.